# How to access PEP-526 local variable annotations in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

I made a variable annotation of a local variable:

```
def a():
    x: int = 1
```

But the annotations dict is empty:

```
> a.__annotations__
{}
```

Same when I use `inspect.get_annotations()` or `typing.get_type_hints()`. How can I access the annotation? Is this feature implemented at all?

I'm using Python 3.10.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the type annotations of global variables, the global `__annotations__` contains them. I don't see an obvious way to do the same for function locals tho.

Means, you can get type annotations from globals, but not from locals, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a way.

As long as a function has a fqdn, its source code can be parsed and local annotations show there.

```
import ast, inspect

def a():
    k: int = 1

print(ast.dump(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(a))))
```

gives

> Module(body=[FunctionDef(name='a', args=arguments(posonlyargs=[], args=[], kwonlyargs=[], kw_defaults=[], defaults=[]), body=[**AnnAssign**(target=Name(**id='k'**, ctx=Store()), **annotation=Name(id='int'**, ctx=Load()), value=Constant(value=1), simple=1)], decorator_list=[])], type_ignores=[])

This is a pretty hacky way, but works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.10 and earlier versions, variable annotations for local variables are not stored in the `__annotations__` attribute of a function. The `__annotations__` attribute is typically used for storing type hints for function arguments and return values.

```py
def a() -> int: 
    x: int = 1
    
> a.__annotations__
{'return': <class 'int'>}
```

Variable annotations for local variables are not stored as metadata in the function object itself, so there is no built-in way to access them directly.